ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft' in Airflow v2.9.0
I have been trying to update an airflow docker image from Airflow v2.2 (Python 3.9) to Airflow v2.9 (Python 3.11). After updating, I get the following errors when trying to run the docker container.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft'

Here is the complete stack trace:


Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 400, in resolve
    found = getattr(found, frag)
Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: module 'airflow.providers' has no attribute 'microsoft'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 400, in resolve

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 402, in resolve
    self.importer(used)
    found = getattr(found, frag)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft'
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
AttributeError: module 'airflow.providers' has no attribute 'microsoft'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 402, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 573, in configure
    self.importer(used)
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft'

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 735, in configure_handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 573, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
    klass = self.resolve(cname)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 735, in configure_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 407, in resolve
    raise v from e
ValueError: Cannot resolve 'airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.log.wasb_task_handler.WasbTaskHandler': No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    klass = self.resolve(cname)
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    settings.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 407, in resolve
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 531, in initialize
    raise v from e
    LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
ValueError: Cannot resolve 'airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.log.wasb_task_handler.WasbTaskHandler': No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    raise e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
    settings.initialize()
    dictConfig(logging_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 823, in dictConfig
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 531, in initialize
    LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 580, in configure
    raise e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'task'
    dictConfig(logging_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 823, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 580, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'task'



Simply running pip to install the module does not work
pip install airflow-providers-microsoft                    # does not exist
pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure       # does not help
pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql       # does not help

There is also seemingly no other information about the airflow microsoft provider in other stack overflow issues. I have found some issues about the google provider (which can be resolved and installed using pip install apache-airflow-providers-google)
Environment

airflow version 2.9.0
python 3.11
The requirements.txt:



aiohttp==3.9.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
alembic==1.13.1
anyio==4.3.0
apache-airflow==2.9.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-io==1.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.11.1
apache-airflow-providers-fab==1.0.2
apache-airflow-providers-ftp==3.7.0
apache-airflow-providers-http==4.10.0
apache-airflow-providers-imap==3.5.0
apache-airflow-providers-smtp==1.6.1
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==5.3.1
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite==3.7.1
apispec==6.6.0
argcomplete==3.2.3
asgiref==3.8.1
asn1crypto==1.5.1
attrs==23.2.0
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.30.1
azure-identity==1.15.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance==10.1.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.4.0
azure-mgmt-resource==23.0.1
Babel==2.14.0
blinker==1.7.0
cachelib==0.9.0
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
click-plugins==1.1.1
clickclick==20.10.2
cligj==0.7.2
colorama==0.4.6
colorlog==4.8.0
ConfigUpdater==3.2
connexion==2.14.2
cron-descriptor==1.4.3
croniter==2.0.3
cryptography==42.0.5
Deprecated==1.2.14
dill==0.3.8
dnspython==2.6.1
docutils==0.20.1
email_validator==2.1.1
filelock==3.13.3
fiona==1.9.6
Flask==2.2.5
Flask-AppBuilder==4.4.1
Flask-Babel==2.0.0
Flask-Caching==2.1.0
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.6.0
Flask-Limiter==3.5.1
Flask-Login==0.6.3
Flask-Session==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.1
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2024.3.1
GeoAlchemy2==0.14.7
geojson==3.1.0
geopandas==0.14.3
google-re2==1.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.63.0
greenlet==3.0.3
grpcio==1.62.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.6
importlib-metadata==7.0.0
importlib_resources==6.4.0
inflection==0.5.1
isodate==0.6.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
jsonschema==4.21.1
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.10.0
limits==3.10.1
linkify-it-py==2.0.3
lockfile==0.12.2
Mako==1.3.2
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
marshmallow==3.21.1
marshmallow-oneofschema==3.1.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.28.2
mdit-py-plugins==0.4.0
mdurl==0.1.2
more-itertools==10.2.0
msal==1.28.0
msal-extensions==1.1.0
multidict==6.0.5
numpy==1.26.4
opentelemetry-api==1.24.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp==1.24.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common==1.24.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc==1.24.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-http==1.24.0
opentelemetry-proto==1.24.0
opentelemetry-sdk==1.24.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.45b0
ordered-set==4.1.0
packaging==24.0
pandas==2.2.1
pathspec==0.12.1
pendulum==3.0.0
platformdirs==3.11.0
pluggy==1.4.0
portalocker==2.8.2
prison==0.2.1
protobuf==4.25.3
psutil==5.9.8
pycparser==2.22
Pygments==2.17.2
PyJWT==2.8.0
pyOpenSSL==24.1.0
pyproj==3.6.1
python-daemon==3.0.1
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-nvd3==0.15.0
python-slugify==8.0.4
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
referencing==0.34.0
requests==2.31.0
requests-toolbelt==1.0.0
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rich==13.7.1
rich-argparse==1.4.0
rpds-py==0.18.0
setproctitle==1.3.3
shapely==2.0.3
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
snowflake-connector-python==3.7.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.5.1
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.52
SQLAlchemy-JSONField==1.0.2
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.41.2
sqlparse==0.4.4
tabulate==0.9.0
tenacity==8.2.3
termcolor==2.4.0
text-unidecode==1.3
time-machine==2.14.1
tomlkit==0.12.4
typing_extensions==4.11.0
tzdata==2024.1
uc-micro-py==1.0.3
unicodecsv==0.14.1
universal_pathlib==0.2.2
urllib3==2.2.1
Werkzeug==2.2.3
wrapt==1.16.0
WTForms==3.1.2
yarl==1.9.4
zipp==3.18.1




docker version 25.0.3
docker image: apache/airflow:slim-2.9.0-python3.11

Question
So, how do I support a microsoft provider for Airflow, or how can I get rid of the error that prevents me from running Airflow?

Found an answer to my problem.
Running the following command installs the microsoft provider package for airflow and removes the error.
pip install 'apache-airflow[azure_blob_storage,azure_data_lake,azure_cosmos,azure_container_instances]'

As found in this answer.
